# django on production 500 server error for User related Model in Admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I have deployed my Django(1.10) site on google compute engine, everything was working fine, but suddenly one of my model throwing 500 Server Error in admin.
I have googled around but couldn't find any solution.
All other models are displaying properly in django admin except only one and that's TaggedArticles model.
Idon't have changed anything in my site, what's can be wrong? as it happens suddenly  to my site.

Here's my code:

**settings.py:**

```
"""
Django settings for brain project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# For a test push to trigger build from codeship.
# Second thing for CodeShip deployment push
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*******************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '35.202.165.136', 'brainresearchtagging.com', 'www.brainresearchtagging.com', ]
# INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'debug_toolbar',
'users',
'article',
'import_export',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'brain.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'brain.wsgi.application'

# DATABASES = {
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USERNAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASS',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        }
}


#Static Storage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-    validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'), ]


# Authentication
LOGIN_URL = 'users:login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'users:dashboard'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'emails')

# Django Import-Export
IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True
```

Here's Tagged Article's model:

```
choices = (
('yes', 'Yes'),
('no', 'No'),
('not sure', 'Not Sure'),
```

)

```
class TaggedArticle(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tagging')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    category_fit = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=255)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='articles')
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255,)
    relevant_feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

**Here's admin.py:**

```
class TaggedArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
date_hierarchy = 'created_at'
fields = ['category_fit', 'article', 'link', 'relevant_feedback', 'category', 'user', 'email']
list_display = ['article', 'link', 'user', 'email', 'relevant_feedback']
list_filter = ['user', 'email']
model = TaggedArticle


admin.site.register(Tagged, TaggedArticleAdmin)
```

**Update:**
When i set debug=True, then it returns the following error:

> ValueError at /admin/users/taggedarticle/
>   Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://www.brainresearchtagging.com/admin/users/taggedarticle/
>   Django Version: 1.10.5
>   Exception Type: ValueError
>   Exception Value:
>   Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?
>   Exception Location: /root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/functions/datetime.py in convert_value, line 181
>   Python Executable:  /root/virEnv/bin/python3.6
>   Python Version: 3.6.1
>   Python Path:
>   ['/root/brain',
>    '/root/brain/brain',
>    '/root/virEnv/bin',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python36.zip',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
>    '/root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf']
>   Server time:    Sat, 18 Nov 2017 11:55:01 +0000

Comment: \What error message are you getting?

Comment: Server Error (500)

Comment: There's no way we can help you without knowing what the error is. You should configure [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/) on your site so that you can track down the source of the error.

Comment: by setting debug=True, it returns                                                 `ValueError at /admin/users/taggedarticle/
Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?
Request URL: http://www.brainresearchtagging.com/admin/users/taggedarticle/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Value: Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?
Exception Location: /root/virEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/functions/datetime.py in convert_value, line 181` Error!

Answer (score 0):

This can be a mysql timezone issue. This is assuming that you have the required libraries from the error.

Check if the below value has been set in your /etc/mysql/my.cnf in [mysqld] section (after that tag). FI no, enter it and then reboot

```
`default-time-zone = 'UTC`'
```

Once you do this and it still doesnt work try flushing after doing the above.

```
mysql> flush tables;
```